# How was Robin able to stand despite being cuffed with Seastone?

Tags: one-piece

In chapter 398 we can see how Robin has enough energy to stand straight, walk around, tell a long story and shout across the ravine, despite being handcuffed with Seastone handcuffs.

[image]

While in chapter 730 we can see how Luffy becomes completely immobilized after touching the bars of the Colosseum.

[image]

Where does Robin get all this energy from? How come her energy isn't completely drained as it was with Luffy's?

Comment: probably because the different on its density, they manipulated the kairoseki in both handcuff and Smoker's jitte. It will hard for them if the prisoner can't walk, but with Smoker's jitte, he need to be able to hold his enemy down, so they apply his jitte with more powerful kairoseki, or more dense kairoseki.

Comment: They mention the same thing about it in [wiki about those Kairoseki Cuffs](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Kairoseki#Items) but I don't trust wiki that much

Answer (score 4):

> Kairoseki(Seastone) is a naturally occurring (though apparently rare) substance that can drain the energy of Devil Fruit Users to the point where they can't consciously control their powers.  Dr. Vegapunk has invented revolutionary ways to use this rare substance. The Marines appear to have vast quantities of it, using it for jail cells, handcuffs, weapons, and the bottoms of battleships.
>
> **The degree of "weakness" induced by the Kairoseki depends on its density and composition; for example, Kairoseki handcuffs rob the prisoner of their abilities, but still allow the prisoner to walk around normally.**

Source :  http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Kairoseki

Answer (score 3):

Read that chapter (169) more carefully then...

[image: Luffy in Crocodile's cage]

Here, Luffy *stands* in Crocodile's Kairoseki cage.

[image: Still in the cage]

Then he states that he has no power. Well, of course, since the cage is made of Seastone.

[image: Smoker kicking Luffy's ass]

Then Smoker kicks his ass and nails him down. And I think regardless of Seastone any of us would have problems standing if Smoker *pushed* his weapon to our chest.

So to answer the question: Robin was in a weak state because of the Seastone handcuffs back then, but she could stand because nobody pushed her down.

Comment: Maybe i chose a poor example. I'll add a couple where we can see luffy drop to the floor because of the seastone like  at the coloseum where luffy loses his footing after touching the bars. Or the one where luffy and smoker were confined on punk hazard unable to stand up

Comment: I justnoticed how usually seastone makes the user completely powerless like u commented on the other answer, while this doesnt look like robin had become powerless at all

Comment: You should choose pictures for Robin where she looked powerless too. Like when Spandam dragged her all over Enies Lobby to the Gates of Justice.

Comment: Also if I remember well Smoker hit Luffy quite some times on Punk Hazard and even that many hits had only a very short effect.

Comment: @PeterRaeves you should add picture of Luffy tied in Kairoseki chain in punk hazard where he was talking normally and not showing any behavior of losing his power. Though he is powerless. If Luffy try to use DF power Kairoseki will decrease his energy but if somebody try to stretch his body part it will and he won't feel energy loss. I think its like when there is sudden change we feel uneasy but after sometime it become normal. Similarly when Luffy touch stone for the 1st time, decrease in power make him feel uneasy. Same reason why Luffy acting normal when chained though he is powerless.

Answer (score 0):

Many Devil Fruits give powers that have to be activated consciously,
ie. they can be "switched on and off" completely. Luffy is a different case,
his body is rubber all the times. He can´t make his body temporarily normal again,
he's deformable while sleeping, etc.

Seastone doesn't affect energy, health and so on, it affects *only* Devil Fruit powers.

As long as Robin doesn't try to use them, nothing would change because of the Seastone handcuffs (well, except for being handcuffs).
Luffy can't get rid of his rubber state, so...

Comment: Seastone has the same effect as the sea. It does affect energy, health and so on. People with DF powers don't drown in the sea because they "forget" how to swim. They can't, because they are powerless.